# Is it possible to have a cross platform multiplayer game on iOS?

Tags: iphone, networking, multiplayer, ios, ipad

Does Apple allow socket programming? I figure if I am able to send and receive UDP packets (at least over wifi) the possibility is there.

Comment: I believe Minecraft Pocket Edition on iOS utilizes TCP for multiplayer, and I don't suppose Apple would have any reason to block UDP.

Comment: -1 No research and off topic. From the FAQ: _"General programming questions more likely belong on Stack Overflow instead of here. A good rule of thumb is to ask yourself: Would a professional game developer give me a better/different/more specific answer to this question than other programmers?"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it, why didn't you even bother to search?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901612/ios-udp-broadcast-vs-php-udp-broadcast) post implies you can, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3517889/207655) links a page @apple which also implies you can.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about socket programming but you could have a server through which the 2 devices can communicate and exchange data.

Or if you don't have a server then you can use [BUMP](http://bu.mp/) for your cross platform game.